# In a box there are $2$ white balls and $1$ black ball. We draw $1$ ball $100$ times (with return).

Tags: probability

In a box there are $2$ white balls and $1$ black ball. We draw $1$ ball $100$ times (with return).
Calculate approximate value that at least 40 times we drew black ball.

Checking conditions

$np=\frac{100}{3}$

$nq=\frac{200}{3}$

$npq=100\cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3}=\frac{200}{9}$

$x\geq39.5$

$z=\frac{39.5-\frac{100}{3}}{\sqrt{\frac{200}{9}}}=1.30$

z table value=$.90320$

Comment: $40$ is small enough to do the problem exactly (well, at least with a machine).  Worth doing that even if you really are after the normal approximation (as a check, if nothing else).  Otherwise, you have an explicit normal distribution and you just want the probability that a random draw from it is less than $40.5$, where the $.5$ is the standard "continuity correction".

Comment: Correction:  I was computing the probability that you drew $40$ or fewer black balls.  Here, you want to go from $39.5$  up.

Comment: The probability of "$40$ or more" is $1$ minus the probability of "fewer than $40$".  It is also $1$ minus the probability of "$39$ or fewer", which is why using $39.5$ might be a reasonable continuity correction

Comment: @Henry.  Yes, agreed.  the point of my "correction" comment was to change the continuity term to $39.5$

Comment: @lulu - I saw your correction after I had typed my response, so changed it to be more general and less targeted

Comment: @Henry  No worries.

Comment: @lulu I got $z=1.84$ and z table value = $.96712$. $96%$ can't be right, now  I am supposed to substract it, what value should I use?

Comment: $n\cdot (1-\frac{1}{3})=100\cdot \frac23=\frac{200}{3}\neq \frac{100}{3}$

Comment: That solution does not look right.  Do it first from the binomial distribution.  Then you'll know the answer and that will help you in evaluating the approximation.

Comment: @callculus isn't this supposed to be probability of failure? There are 3 balls total and 2 white balls so I thought $\frac{2}{3}$ would be right

Comment: Yes, it is right. But you have $\frac{100}3$

Comment: @callculus Yeah I see now, I put chance of failure in bracket $n \cdot (1-\frac{2}{3})$, but its supposed to be 1-(chance of success).

Comment: Change this and see what comes out, particularly the standard deviation at the denominator.

Comment: @callculus I corrected values (hopefully), what should I do now?

Comment: Looks good but $\frac{39.5-\frac{100}{3}}{\sqrt{\frac{200}{9}}}=1.30815=1.31$ (rounded to two decimal places). Looking at a table we get $\Phi(1.31)=0.90490$. This is $P(X\leq 39)$ You want the converse probability $1-P(X\leq 39)$

Comment: Using the binomial distribution I get $P(X \geq 40)=0.0966$. So the approximation is good enough for the most purposes. A linear interpolation can be applied to get a more exact value from the table.

Comment: @callculus So the chance to get at least 40 black balls is 9.51%?

Comment: @fakerakerp Yes. But don´t forget the word approximately, since it is an approximation.

Comment: Alright, thanks for help everyone